# I want to specify a TimeZone as GMT but create a DateTime that is local (EST);

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I want to specify a time in GMT timezone, and then convert it to the local TimeZone which is EST.

This appears to do what I want, but seems a long way to get there!

Is there a simpler way to achieve this:

```
public static TimeZoneInfo edtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    public static TimeZoneInfo gmtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    public static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

 DateTime edtStartDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00)), DateTimeKind.Unspecified), gmtZone, edtZone);
```

Comment: A good answer is given but question clarification could help: (A) Do you truly mean GMT or do you really mean UTC?  And do you explicitly want Eastern Standard Time, or do you really want the local time (which just happens to be Eastern)?  If you were running this in Chicago, do you still want Eastern or would Central then be used?

Answer (score 0):

This is *probably* what you are looking for:

```
// A timespan isn't really a time-of-day, but we'll let that slide for now.
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);

// Use the current utc date, at that time.
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Add(time);

// Convert to the US Eastern time zone.
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime easternDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, tz);
```

Note that we're pairing the current UTC date with the time you provided.  Since US Eastern time is either 5 or 4 hours behind UTC, with 18:00 you will always get the same date.  But if you were using a different time, such as 00:00, you would find that the resulting Eastern time was on the *prior* day.  This is normal.

A couple of notes about your previous code:

- The Windows Time Zone ID `"Eastern Standard Time"` refers to *both* EST and EDT.  It really should have been called "Eastern Time".  Don't let the name confuse the issue.
- GMT and UTC are mostly the same for all modern usage.  Unless you are referring to the time zone used in London, you should prefer the term UTC.
- The Windows Time Zone ID `"GMT Standard Time"` is not actually for GMT/UTC.  It is specifically the time zone used in London, which alternates between GMT (UTC+00:00) and BST (UTC+01:00).  If you want a `TimeZoneInfo` representing UTC, the ID is just "UTC".  (However, you don't really need that in this case.)
- Your original code assumed used `DateTime.Now.Date`, which would assume the date in the computer's local time zone - which might not be *either* UTC or Eastern.
- If you find yourself using `DateTime.SpecifyKind`, in most situations, you're probably doing something wrong.  (The exception would be when loading or deserializing.)

Regarding my note about a `TimeSpan` not being a true time-of-day, this is how .NET would have you handle that:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("18:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Add(time.TimeOfDay);
```

Or even uglier in one line:

```
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.Parse("18:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Personally, I would rather use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), which has a separate `LocalTime` type explicitly for a time-of-day that's not bound to a specific date.  I'm also working to get `System.TimeOfDate` and `System.Date` types [added to the CoreCLR](https://github.com/mj1856/corefx-dateandtime).

Comment: Could of named `time` to be `offset` and not worried about a time-of-day.  But from watching your own PluralSight training and reading on NodaTime, I just want to point out that GMT is not the same as UTC.  I learned that from you.  I'm just guessing that you were guessing that the OP really meant UTC when he said GMT, but if he didn't, then  your answer is wrong.

Comment: @RickDavin - Hmmm...  I think perhaps you misunderstood, as I recall stating in the PS course that GMT and UTC are mostly the same, except for how they are legally defined and how they originated in history.  Glad to see you watched though! :)

Comment: See [the third item in module 1](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=matt-johnson&name=date-time-fundamentals-m1-intro&mode=live&clip=2&course=date-time-fundamentals). :)